# How can I change the PFP of my bot Discord

Tags: discord, discord.py

I'm trying to change the pfp of my bot by a gif like the pfp of the bot emoji.gg do

asked teh question on the reddit r/discordapp and someone gave me the docs of the Discord devlopper portal but I don't understand a lot of things of the documentation (I'm a beginner)
So I do this post to find help
Already thanks for ur help ❤️
Here the link the user send me : https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/user
https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/user#modify-current-user

Answer (score 0):

The discord.py docs are probably going to be more helpful if that's indeed what your using. https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.ClientUser.edit would be the relevant method. Assuming you have your bot setup as a class, you would would want to do something along the lines of:

```
class TheBot(discord.Client):
     ....

bot = TheBot()
with open(path_to_your_img, mode='rb') as file:
    await bot.user.edit(avatar=file.read())
```

or, if I remember correctly, the bot will block when initialized so you'll have to change the avatar by setting the on_ready method of your bot class. My guess is the avatar will persist, so you'll probably want to remove the method after you set it or add some sort of check.

```
class TheBot(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready():
        with open(path_to_your_img, mode='rb') as file:
            await self.user.edit(avatar=file.read())
```